# In game programming are global variables bad?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I know my gut reaction to global variables is "badd!" but in the two game development courses I've taken at my college globals were used extensively, and now in the DirectX 9 game programming tutorial I am using (www.directxtutorial.com) I'm being told globals are okay in game programming ...?  The site also recommends using only structs if you can when doing game programming to help keep things simple.

I'm really confused on this issue, and all the research I've been trying to do is very confusing.  I realize there are issues when using global variables (threading issues, they make code harder to maintain, the state of them is hard to track etc) but also there is a cost associated with not using globals, I'd have to pass a loooot of information around very often which can be confusing and I imagine time-costing, although I guess pointers would speed the process up (this is my first time writing a game in C++.)  Anyway, I realize there is probably no "right" or "wrong" answer here since both ways *work*, but I want my code to be as proper as I can so any input would be good, thank you very much!

Comment: Hmmm... Are misused global variables bad?

Comment: Passing information isn't that bad. Just use pointers.

Comment: Each time you use globals, god kills a kitten.

Comment: @ereOn but Jesus resurrects it, so it's OK.

Comment: Lol? Pointers are essential in a language like C, and have been correctly removed from higher languages like py, php and java.

Comment: @Lo'oris - IMHO pointers are the best thing about C, I wouldn't loose them for the world ;)

Comment: The problem with internet tutorials addressing C++ programmers is that 90% of them are total crap.

Comment: Well I don't claim to know how well the tutorial is written in terms of conforming with good programming practices, but I don't want to make it sound like it's a bad website.  It's got a lot of really good information pertaining to DirectX, at least from everything I've learned so far.  I could be wrong but I'm still happy I paid to become a premium member on the site.

Comment: @Aiden: having not been programming in C in a lot of years, I got used not to have them :/ at first I was shocked, because I was still thinking C-like, then if you actually *feel* the new language, you realize they can be avoided in that language: there's a different way to do stuff. That said, in php `foreach` loops I often miss them.

Comment: It seems that there are two common types of C++ tutorials online: those that pretend like you are programming in Java (`int x = new int();` everywhere) and those that pretend like you are programming in C ("use structs because they are simpler" and `void *` everywhere). If the argument is that you should avoid any sort of object-oriented programming because it's simpler, you might as well program entirely in assembly on a single-instruction-set computer, where all of your code is subtract and branch. How much simpler can it get than just one function!?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The trouble with games and globals is that games (nowadays) are threaded at engine level. Game developers using an engine use the engine's abstractions rather than directly programming concurrency (IIRC). In many of the highlevel languages such as C++, threads sharing state is complex. When many concurrent processes share a common resource they have to make sure they don't tread on eachother's toes.

To get around this, you use *concurrency control* such as mutex and various locks. This in effect makes asynchronous critical sections of code access shared state in a synchronous manner for writing. The topic of concurrency control is too much to explain fully here.

Suffice to say, if threads run with global variables, it makes debugging very hard, as concurrency bugs are a nightmare (think, *"which thread wrote that? Who holds that lock?"*).

There **are exceptions** in games programming API such as OpenGL and DX. If your shared data/globals are pointers to DX or OpenGL graphics contexts then typically this maps down to GPU operations which don't suffer so much from the same trouble.

Just be careful. Keeping objects representing 'player' or 'zombie' or whatever, and sharing them between threads can be tricky. Spawn 'player' threads and 'zombie group' threads instead and have a robust concurrency abstraction between them based on message passing rather than accessing those object's state across the thread/critical section boundary.

Saying all that, I do agree with the **"Say no to globals"** point made below.

For more on the complexities of threads and shared state see:

1 [POSIX Threads API - I know it is POSIX, but provides a good idea that translates to other API](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)
2 [Wikipedia's excellent range of articles on concurrency control mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Concurrency_control)
3 [The Dining Philosopher's problem (and many others)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)
4 [ThreadMentor tutorials and articles on threading](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/)
5 [Another Intel article, but more of a marketing thing.](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/multithreaded-game-programming-and-hyper-threading-technology/)
6 [An ACM article on building multi-threaded game engines](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1231894.1231896)

Comment: Thank you.  It will take me a while to read through all of those links but your message makes sense and it seems like a much more robust system than what I had originally planned anyway.  So, thanks again!

Comment: On your point to the shared state in OpenGL, for example, this is exactly the "bad" kind of state.  You don't want to be willy nilly changing GL state whenever or wherever you want.  For one reason, you don't want the state changed by "someone else" while you were just about to draw something.  Another reason is that random state changes will destroy your runtime performance.

Answer (score 25):

Have worked on AAA game titles, I can tell you that globals should be eradicated immediately before they spread like a cancer. I've seen them corrupt an I/O subsystem so completely that it had to be wholly thrown out to be rewritten.

Say no to globals. Always.

Comment: C++ isn't fully OO. Trying to force everything into OO doesn't really work. Same kind of goes for Win32, I guess. Finding globals scattered all over the place is bad design, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: +1, I cannot agree more, globals always lead to bad habbits and cluttering, not matter what the project is. @John: you can easyily combat copius amounts of globals using singlton objects/static methods to delegate over any global data you might need(such as a DC), this keeps stuff centralized, clean and prevents duplication, C++ 'OO enough' to handle that just fine :P

Comment: @John, I don't see the relevance here - you don't need OO to remove global variables. You can write a C app with everything in functions and structs and not a global in sight.

Comment: @Necrolis: wrapping globals in a singleton is just pretending you fixed the problem. Forcing it OO doesn't make it better.

Comment: @Kylotan - you mean like a Haskell-style way of C-programming? I don't think you can write a Windows C program without having to store cross-function data, since you aren't calling all the functions - Windows calls callbacks and you need the data.

Comment: @John I agree, Singletons are at least as bad as globals.

Comment: Hum... but what's the difference between a Singleton and a global ??? globals are not bad because they are labelled "globals" they are bad because they introduce a globally shared state and I fail to see what's the Singleton is bringing to the table for that particular problem (disregarding initialization/destruction issues).

Comment: @Matthieu M. there isn't much difference between the two. One just has  a fancy name.

Comment: @John - I have no idea exactly what you're referring to I'm afraid. I've written many Windows programs without extensive use of callbacks, and the one or two callbacks I did use typically had some user-supplied context that you can use, typically via an LPVOID or the like.

Comment: singletons are better than globals because they prevent namespace cluttering, and they allow a lot more checking on the global they wrap(ie: prevent bad/invalid assignments), with things like __declspec(property) in MSVC. you can also group related globals a lot more efficiently, and lock them for synchronicity. I'm by no means saying you should create singltons all willy nilly just to replace globals, but in situations when you really must provide a global level state(such as Lua script state), then they provide the needed security

Comment: @Necrolis make no mistake, a Singleton *is* a global.

Comment: oh, I'm not saying it is, i'm just saying its a little safer than a raw extern'd variable, I don't even use singletons for this, just thought I'd explore the avenue :)

Comment: Why must a Lua script state be a singleton? There's nothing intrinsic to a lua_State that means you must always have one, only one, and that it should be accessible from all parts of your program and all threads. Lots of people I know use multiple lua_States, for example.

Answer (score 7):

In this respect, there's no difference between games and other programs. While arguably OK in small examples given in elementary courses, global variables are strongly discouraged in real programs.

So if you want to write correct, readable and maintainable code, stay away from global variables as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

All answers until now deal with the globals/threads issue, but I will add my 2 cents to the struct/class (understood as all public attributes/private attributes + methods) discussion. Preferring structs over classes on the grounds of that being simpler is in the same line of thought of preferring assembler over C++ on the grounds of that being a simpler language.

The fact that you have to think on how your entities are going to be used and provide methods for it makes the concrete entity a little more complex, but greatly simplifies the rest of the code and maintainability. The whole point of encapsulation is that it simplifies the program by providing clear ways in that your data can be modified while maintaining your objects invariants. You control the entry points and what can happen there. Having all attributes public imply that any part of the code can have a small innocent error (forgot to check condition X) and break your invariants completely (health below 0,  but no 'death' processing being triggered)

The other common discussion is performance: If I just need to update a datum, then having to call a method will impact my performance. Not really. If methods are simple and you provide them in the header as inlines (inside the class body or outside with the `inline` keyword), the compiler will be able to copy those instructions to each use place. You get the guarantee that the compiler will not leave out any check by mistake, and no impact in performance.

Comment: Using inlines can still affect performance. If you inline so much that the critical section of your code no longer fits in cache, you may find speed losses due to cache misses.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: +1 (+10 if I could): It's a horrible trap to fall into too; very difficult to dig yourself out, especially as colleagues tend to try to “reoptimize” things back into the local optimum while you're getting out of the hole. Sometimes, there's no alternative but to read the damn disassembled code, realize that you're in trouble, and start telling the compiler to stop inlining.

Comment: @David structs and classes are basically equivalent in C++

Comment: @FredOverflow: I know they are the same, that is what the comment in the parenthesis meant to say: in the rest of the answer the struct will be used as 'all public attributes' while class as 'private attributes + methods'. I guess it was not clear enough.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: I know about the problem of excessive inlining. The fact is that in C++ having the methods marked as inline does not mean that they will actually be inlined. The compiler will decide when to inline and when not to, and the compiler will most probably make a better choice --for sure, it knows better than I do.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: if you're manually copying the method instead of having the compiler inline it, you're not earning anything in term of performance but a whole load of hurt in term of maintenance... anyway `inline` is a hint, hell even VS `__forceinline` is a hint ;)

Comment: Re: comments about inlining being a hint. Yes, of course. That doesn't change my comment, though; if the compiler decides to inline so much that the critical section grows too big, you'll have problems.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: Even for a simple accessor? `int health() const { return m_health; }`? I don't think so. Providing *complex* functions in the headers is ugly, but simple one-liner accessor or dispatchers are just fine (and I even recommend it)

Comment: I am no C++ programmer so I won't argue, but it looks ugly to me. If I worked on a big C++ code base maybe I would change my mind. (My gut feeling is that the simple accessor is an implementation detail.)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I find that accessors are generally bad design. If you want to make the data public, you might as well just make it public. Rather than adding `getX()` and `setX()` member functions all over the place, I find it more useful to create functions that give traits of my class. Does the rest of the code really need the exact HP that someone has? Generally not, and the better solution is simply something like `is_alive()`, which checks if hp >= 0, for instance. Rather than `a.set_health(a.get_health() - 10);`, use `a.damage(10);`, or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Having read a bit more what you posted though:

> I'm being told globals are okay in
>   game programming ...? The site also
>   recommends using only structs if you
>   can when doing game programming to
>   help keep things simple.

Games code is no different from other code really. *Gratuitous* use of globals is bad regardless. And as for 'only use structs', that is just a load of crap. Approach game development on the same principles as any other software - you may find places where you need to bend this but they should be the exception, typically when dealing with low-level hardware issues.

Comment: That's just an excuse game programmers give to a)make themselves feel special b)excuse bad design. I should know, I used to _be_ one.

Comment: It seems like the same principles apply to all software: Focus first on what the software needs to do, and prefer the most readable version. If you then find you need to improve performance (focusing on how the software does it), you measure what's taking the most time and improve that. Whether you are writing a game, a text editor, a VCR, or the controls of a nuclear power plant, this seems to be the best course of action.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the advice about globals and 'keeping things simple' is probably a mixture of being easier to learn and old fashioned thinking about performance. When I was being taught about game programming I remember being told that C++ wasn't advised for games as it would be too slow but I've worked on multiple games using every facet of C++ which proves that isn't true.

I would add to everyone's answers here that globals are to be avoided where possible, I wouldn't be afraid to use whatever you need from C++ to make your code understandable and easy to use. If you come up against a performance problem then profile that specific issue and I'll bet that most of the time you won't need to remove use of a C++ feature but just think about your problem better. There may still be some platforms around that require pure C but I don't really have experience of them, even the Gameboy Advance seemed to deal with C++ quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The metaissue here is that of state.  How much state does any given function depend on, and how much does it change?  Then consider how much state is implicit versus explicit, and cross that with the inspect vs. change.

If you have a function/method/whatever that is called DoStuff(), you have no idea from the outside what it depends on, what it needs, and what's going to happen to the shared state.  If this is a class member, you also have no idea how that object's state is going to mutate.  This is bad.

Contrast to something like cosf(2), this function is understood not to *change* any global state, and any state that it requires (lookup tables for example) are hidden from view and have no effect on your program-at-large.  This is a function that computes a value based on what you give it and it returns that value.  It changes no state.

Class member functions then have the opportunity to step up some problems.  There's a *huge* difference between

```
myObject.hitpoints -= 4;
myObject.UpdateHealth();
```

and

```
myObject.TakeDamage(4);
```

In the first example, an external operation is changing some state that one of its member functions implicitly depends upon.  The fact is that these two lines can be separated by many other lines of code begins to make it non-obvious what's going to happen in the UpdateHealth call, even if outside of the subtraction it is the same as the TakeDamage call.  Encapsulating the state changes (in the second example) implies that the specifics of the state changes aren't important to the outside world, and hopefully they're not.  In the first example, the state changes are *explicitly* important to the outside world, and this is really no different than setting some globals and calling a function that uses those globals.  E.g. hopefully you'd never see

```
extern float value_to_sqrt;
value_to_sqrt = 2.0f;
sqrt();  // reads the global value_to_sqrt
extern float sqrt_value; // has the results of the sqrt.
```

And yet, how many people do exactly this sort of thing in other contexts?  (Considering especially that class instance state is "global" in regards to that particular instance.)

So- prefer giving explicit instruction to your function calls, and prefer that they return the results directly rather than having to explicitly set state before calling a function and then checking other state after it returns.

The more state dependencies a bit of code has, the harder it'll be to make it multithread safe, but that has already been covered above.  The point I want to make is that the problem isn't so much globals but more the visibility of the collection of state that is required for a bit of code to operate (and subsequently how much other code also depends on that state).

Comment: This is without a doubt the best answer. Everything I tried to explain in comments this does better and more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Most games aren't multi-threaded, although newer titles are going down that route, and so they've managed to get away with it so far.
Saying that globals are okay in games is like not bothering to fix the brakes on your car because you only drive at 10mph!
It's bad practice which ever way you look at it.
You only have to look at the number of bugs in games to see examples of this.

Comment: Xbox360 has 3 dual-core processors and the PS3 has a main processor and 6 vector processors.  Both also have additional dedicated graphics processors.  In what sense are "most" games on these platforms not multithreaded?

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: To be fair, he didn't say "most games on the latest generation of hardware", nor even "most AAA games", he just said "most games", and therefore I think the statement holds true, even if you only count commercial games of the last 10 years, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If in class A you need to access data D, instead of setting D global, you'd better put into A a reference to D.

Answer (score 2):

Globals are NOT intrinsically bad. In C for instance they are part of the language's normal use... and since C++ builds on C they still have a place.

On an aesthetic level, it's better to avoid them where you can sensibly make them part of a class, but if all you do is wrap a bunch of globals into a singleton, you made things worse because at least with globals it's *obvious* what the point is.

Be careful, but for some things it makes less sense to force OO concepts on what is actually a global value.

Comment: Especially in C++, gobals are a **huge** problem (think order of initialization and destruction!). Furthermore, better solutions exist in C++. There are a few notable exceptions (`cin`, `cout`) but apart from these, globals should be avoided completely in C++.

Comment: C++ is NOT a pure OO language and you are using it wrong trying to force this approach. It offers a mix of procedural/OO. If you want a proper OO language, use one instead.

Comment: C++ also supports functional programming (for example via `boost::bind`, `boost::lambda` and now anonymous functions and closures in C++0x) and template metaprogramming, among others :)

Answer (score 2):

Two specific issues that I've encountered in the past:

**First:** If you're attempting to separate e.g. render phase (const access to most game state) from logic phase (non-const access to most game state) for whatever reason (decoupling render rate from logic rate, synchronizing game state across a network, recording and playback of gameplay at a fixed point in the frame, etc), globals make it very hard to enforce that.

Problems tend to creep in and become hard to debug and eradicate.   This also has implications for threaded renderers separate from game logic, or the like (the other answers cover this topic thoroughly).

**Second:** The presence of many globals tends to bloat the [literal pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_pool), which the compiler typically places after each function.

If you get to your state through either a single "struct GlobalTable" which holds globals or a collection of methods on an object or the like, your literal pool tends to be a lot smaller, decreasing the size of the `.text` section in your executable.

This is mostly a concern for instruction set architectures that can't embed load targets directly into instructions (see e.g. fixed-width ARM or Thumb version 1 instruction encoding on ARM processors).  Even on modern processors I'd wager you'll get slightly smaller codegen.

It also hurts doubly when your instruction and data caches are separate (again, as on some ARM processors); you'll tend to get two cachelines loaded where you might only need one with a unified cache.  Since the literal pool may count as data, and won't always start on a cacheline boundary, the same cacheline might have to be loaded both into the i-cache and d-cache.

This may count as a "microoptimization", but it's a transform that's relatively easily applied to an entire codebase (e.g. `extern struct GlobalTable { /* ... */ } the;` and then replace all `g_foo` with `the.foo`)... And we've seen code size decrease between 5 and 10 percent in some cases, with a corresponding boost to performance due to keeping the caches cleaner.

Comment: I had no idea about any of that, thank you very much for sharing it!  I'm always interested in learning how to optimize code, and this sounds like a great trick :D

Comment: My pleasure.  Remember, though, as with anything that looks like a "trick" you should always make sure you need it before applying it -- use a profiler, or check disasm before and after.  It's worthwhile to try things like this as experiments (if you're not on a deadline), to gain better understanding, but not always worth keeping the results.  =)  Stuff like this tends to vary so much from compiler to compiler and from CPU to cpu that the "show me the profile" mantra is always worth keeping in mind.

Comment: With regard to the literal pool, I wonder why the ARM ABI didn't specify the use of a global-variable-base register the way the old Mac OS did?  That would allow up to 4K of globals to be accessed directly, and an additional 1024K to be accessed with one extra (non-load) instruction [e.g. add r0,r4,#(93 << 12)] when using the ARM instruction set.

Comment: @supercat: if I had to guess, I'd say two things.  Special purpose registers are kind of anathema to RISC and power-conscious architectures; you don't want something you have to keep lit up that isn't going to be actively used a lot.  (I'm not sure about the exact tradeoff here, the preceding is more just a shot in the dark.)  Second, global location is a link-time thing; how you access the global in terms of instructions generated is a compile-time thing.  Unless you have link-time code gen, you have to pessimistically assume your global ended up somewhere outside that range.

Comment: For non-toy programs you're above 5K of static data quickly, in my experience, too...  And how do you decide where to point the base register in the case of e.g. .bss being located separately from .rodata?  It's not an easy problem -- something we give up to have flexibility at link time.  However, you can get most of the benefit using patterns like `struct GlobalTable`...  The compiler will likely schedule a register for your globaltable pointer throughout the method.

Comment: @leander: For many applications in the embedded-systems world (which is what the ARM is targeting), being able to designate 4K worth of variables for "fast" access, and 1024K worth for "relatively fast" access could save a lot of code.  Throwing everything in a struct can be helpful, but would increase source-code verbosity and would require each method to fetch a reference to the structure on entry.  Your point about `.rodata` is a good one, though I would expect that non-pointer/array-based accesses to read-only data are *much* less common than accesses to global *variables*.

Comment: @leander: To be sure, embedded systems often use globals to a much greater extent than other applications, so the comparative benefit of dedicating a register for global addressing would be less in "computer" applications than in embedded systems, but even in computer applications the facility could still be useful if directed toward a different purpose: thread-local variables.

Comment: Yep, definitely!  We have actually played games with the linker map to get the global table and other frequently accessed mutables (IRQ tables, etc) into TCM on chip.  =)  Re computer applications, the sticking point with stuff like TCM seems to be being fair in the OS with other applications -- but a dedicated register is smaller and would just be included in context switch logic, so could work.

Comment: @leander: TCM?  Turner Classic Movies? Traditional Chinese Medicine? Thread something Memory?  Having a dedicated register which remains constant for any given thread would seem to allow efficient thread-local variables at relatively slight cost; even if as policy everything is a single-indirection removed from the register itself, that would be no worse than normal "global" access.

Comment: @supercat: Tightly Coupled Memory.  On-core.  Sometimes you can designate part of the cache as regular memory, sometimes it's separate.  Shows up a lot in the ARM7TDMI devices we've worked with.

Comment: @leander: What do you think of having a register dedicated for thread-locals?  In a lot of frameworks, thread-local variables are much more expensive than globals from a code perspective, but globals require interlocking.  If threads want to collectively maintain something like a running total which can be polled occasionally, and the identities of the threads in question are known, having each thread keep a total and having the poll routine sum together the total from each thread could be more efficient than using a global with an interlocked increment, but only if thread-local access...

Comment: ...is fast.  Having the code in each thread pass around a reference to object which is owned by the thread wouldn't be impossible, but it's awkward at best.  Especially with statically-liked applications, being able to specify a special memory area for thread-locals would seem the best approach.

Comment: @supercat: dredging through memory, then looking around: it looks like GS and FS (used to be segment-specific) regs are used for TLS on x86.  Some interesting articles on how Chromium / NaCl is protecting that stuff on different platforms...  McKenney's parallel programming book (WIP) covers exactly the counter case you mention, I think, and several variants, but doesn't specify the TLS mechanism...  So: yes, seems like a great idea, proofed in at least some OSes/architectures.  =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a risk and say it depends to me on the scope/scale of your project. Because if you are trying to program an epic game with a boatload of code, then globals could, and easily in the most painful way in hindsight, cost you way more time than they save.

But if you are trying to code, say, something as simple as Super Mario or Metroid or Contra or even simpler, like Pac-Man, then these games were originally coded in 6502 assembly and used globals for almost everything. Just about all the game data and state was stored in data segments, and that didn't stop the devs from shipping a very competent and popular product in spite of working with absolutely inferior tools and engineering standards which would probably horrify people today.

So if you are just writing this kind of small and simple game which has a very limited scope and isn't designed to grow and expand far beyond its original design, isn't designed to be maintained for years and years, with a few thousand lines of simple C++ code, then I don't see the big deal of using a global here or a singleton there. Someone obsessed with trying to engineer Super Mario with the soundest engineering techniques with SOLID and a DI framework could end up taking far, far longer to ship than even the devs who wrote it in 6502 asm.

And I'm getting old and there's something to it there when I look at these old simple games and how they were coded, and it almost seems like the devs were doing something right in spite of the hard-coded magic numbers and globals all over the place while I spend my career fumbling around and trying to figure out the best way to engineer things. That said this is probably a very unpopular opinion, and not one I would have liked either a decade or two ago, but there's something to it. I don't look at the 6502 asm of Metroid and think, *"these devs underengineered their product and their lives would have been so much easier if they did this or that."* Seems like they did things just about right.

But again this is for small-scale stuff, maybe in the indie category of games by today's standards, and in the smaller of the indie games among them, and far from doing anything ground-breaking in terms of how much data it can process or using cutting-edge hardware techniques. If in doubt, I'd definitely suggest to err on the side of avoiding globals. It's also a little bit trickier in C++ as opposed to say, C, since you can have objects with constructor and destructors, and initialization and destruction order isn't well-defined and easily predictable for global objects. There I'd say to lean even more on the side of avoiding globals since they can trip you up in whole new ways when you aren't explicitly initializing and destroying them yourself in a predictable order. And naturally if you want to multithread a lot beyond a critical loop here and there, then your ability to reason about thread-safety of any particular code will be severely diminished if you cannot minimize the scope/visibility of your game state to the minimum of places.