# Access global queue object in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am building a messaging app in python that interfaces with twitter I want to create a global fifo queue that the twitterConnection object can access to insert new messages.

this is the main section of the app:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from twitterConnector import TwitterConnector
    from Queue import deque

    #instantiate the request queue
    requestQueue = deque()

    #instantiate the twitter connector
    twitterInterface = TwitterConnector()

    #Get all new mentions
    twitterInterface.GetMentions()
```

Specifically I want to be able to call the .GetMentions() method of the TwitterConnector class and process any new mentions and put those messages into the queue for processing separately.

This is the twitterConnector class so far:

```
class TwitterConnector:
   def __init__(self):
      self.connection = twitter.Api(consumer_key=self.consumer_key,consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret,access_token_key=self.access_token_key,access_token_secret=self.access_token_secret)
      self.mentions_since_id = None

   def VerifyCredentials(self):
      print self.connection.VerifyCredentials()

   def GetMentions(self):
      mentions = self.connection.GetMentions(since_id=self.mentions_since_id)
      for mention in mentions:
         print mention.text
         global requestQueue.add(mention)  # <- error
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update: let me see if I can clarify the use case a bit. My TwitterConnector is intended to retrieve messages and will eventually transform the twitter status object into a simplified object that contains the needed information for downstream processing. In the same method, it will perform some other calculations to try to determine other needed information. It is actually the transformed objects that I want to put into the queue. hopefully that makes sense. As a simplified example, this method would map the twitter status object to a new object that would contain properties such as: origin network (twitter), username, message, and location if available. This new object would then be put into the queue.

eventually there will be other connectors for other messaging systems that will perform similar actions. They will receive a message populate the new message object and place them into the same queue for further processing. Once the message has been completely processed a response would be formulated and then added to an appropriate queue for transmittal. Using the new object described above the once the actual processing of the tweet content took place then based upon the origin network and username a response might be returned to the originator via twitter.

I had thought of passing a reference to the queue in the contractor (or as an argument to the method) I had also thought of modifying the method to return a list of the new objects and iterate over them to put them into the queue, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better or more efficient way to handle this. I also wish to be able to do the same thing with a logging object and a database handler. Thoughts?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I'm gonna ask you the obvious: why are you defining your own `TwitterConnector` and not using existing Python APIs instead?

Comment: For robust shared queues you may want to use AMQP. Take a look at Celery.

Comment: I suggest making all these queue input points derive from the same base class with a method "add_to_queue" and a constructor that receives the queue objects.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that "global" should appear on a line of its own

```
global requestQueue
requestQueue.add(mention)
```

Moreover, the requestQueue must appear in the module that is defining the class.

If you are importing the requestQueue symbol from another class, you don't need the global at all.

```
from some_module import requestQueue
class A(object):
    def foo(o):
         requestQueue.add(o) # Should work
```

Comment: Agreed. On syntactic level this is a valid solution, but it doesn't solve problems with the design.

Comment: My philosophy is first answer the man, then tell him why the question is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

**It is generally good idea to avoid globals**; a better design often exists. For details on the issue of globals see for instance ([[1]](http://softwarewhys.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/why-globals-should-be-avoided/), [[2]](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), [[3]](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832263/in-game-programming-are-global-variables-bad)).

If by using globals you wish to share a single `requestQueue` between multiple `TwitterConnector` instances, you could also pass the queue to the connector in its constructor:

```
class TwitterConnector:
   def __init__(self, requestQueue):
      self.requestQueue = requestQueue
      ...

   def GetMentions(self):
      mentions = self.connection.GetMentions(since_id = self.mentions_since_id)
      requestQueue = deque()
      for mention in mentions:
         print mention.text
         self.requestQueue.add(mention)
```

Correspondingly, you need to provide your `requestQueue` to the constructor as:

```
twitterInterface = TwitterConnector(requestQueue)
```

Comment: I agree about not using globals but Singletons are still a very valid pattern. The just need to be defined on a different module so they can be imported as symbols

Comment: You assume that every call to GetMentions CAN return a different queue and they don't need to be aggregated over time. That is a major functional difference from what he attempted to do

Comment: A valid point. Refactored. I also agree that there is nothing wrong with singletons, but I don't see a point using such pattern here (why would we want to make `twitterConnector` depend on a specific app that uses it?).

Comment: If this is not an integral part of the TwitterConnector, so maybe the right thing to do is pass it as an argument to the GetMentions method. But really we need a deeper understanding of what the purpose is. There is already an API he is using for the connection so maybe TwitterConnecter is just a bad name.

Comment: I totally agree with you on that. With this information we can provide him only with some hacks.